# How to write PILcode with opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter

im_rgb = Image.open('x.JPG')
im_a = Image.open('blackandwhitex.png').convert('L').resize(im_rgb.size)

im_rgba = im_rgb.copy()
im_rgba.putalpha(im_a)
im_rgba.save('xtransparent.png')
```

Thanks to this code I made transparent on blacka and put another photo on it, so in the end I have transparent background.

How it will be look like in opencv. I need open cv, because PIL rotate photos. But it is hard to write this for someone new in opencv and google colab.

[image]

I've made transparent black using this code:

```
import cv2
file_name = "x.png"

src = cv2.imread(file_name, 1)
tmp = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,alpha = cv2.threshold(tmp,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
b, g, r = cv2.split(src)
rgba = [b,g,r, alpha]
dst = cv2.merge(rgba,4)
cv2.imwrite("newx.png", dst)
```

[image]

It's not so good...

[image]

After puttingc togehter second and third photo I want this:

[image]

It is the input of using PIL. (All images have the same size.)

Comment: Please provide (a) all original input images (maybe downsized, if they're really somewhat `[4000 x 5000]`), so that reproducing is possible, and (b) the actual output of your PIL save, so that comparison is possible. What is your _actual problem_? Is there too much "black" remaining in your OpenCV version? (Then, adapt the threshold!?)

Comment: The size of images is ok, i can't upload them in orignal size, because they are heavy. The problem is that the photo after imshow() is flipped while using PIL. Changig imshow parameter origin to 'lower' nothing helped. So I think I must write the code in opencv. I need some tips how to write it in opencv or maybe using PIL. The last photo is my OUTPUT (mistake) of using PIL and rotate the photo before.

Answer (score 0):

Show color photo:

```
%pylab inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img2=mpimg.imread('colorphoto.JPG')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img2)
plt.show()
```

Some photos are flipped after that.

Show black and white photo:

```
%pylab inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img2=mpimg.imread('bawphoto.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img2)
plt.show()
```

For some of the photos I need to use:

```
from PIL import Image
def rotate(image_path, saved_location):

    image_obj = Image.open(image_path)
    transposed  = image_obj.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)
    transposed  = transposed.transpose(Image.ROTATE_180)
    transposed.save(saved_location)
    transposed.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = 'colorphoto.JPG'

    rotate(image, 'rotated_colorphoto.JPG')
```

And after that I convert them into one photo:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter

im_rgb = Image.open('rotated_colorphoto.JPG')
im_a = Image.open('bawphoto.png').convert('L').resize(im_rgb.size)
im_rgba = im_rgb.copy()
im_rgba.putalpha(im_a)
im_rgba.save('imagewithtransparentbackground.png')
```

I don't want flipped photos. I need them original size not flipped..